# Javascript Taxi Fare Calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of issues understanding how to complete this task and will appreciate a bit of guidance where i'm going wrong:

> Northdrivers Taxi Company™️ have asked for your help writing a function which will calculate the cost of getting to the party! Journeys are priced as follows:
>
> - Journeys up to 3 minutes long have a flat base rate cost of £5
> - Every minute after the first 3 will cost an extra 70p
> - The length of the journey is always rounded up to a whole number of minutes
>
> The calculateTaxiFare function should take a number representing the length of a taxi journey in seconds, and return a number representing the cost of that journey in pence.

my code:

```js
function calculateTaxiFare(seconds) {
    // Your code goes here...
    const flatFare = 500
    
 const minutes = Math.ceil(seconds / 60)

console.log(minutes)

if(minutes<=3){
    return(flatFare)
}
if(minutes>3){
    let newMin = minutes-3;
    return (flatFare + (newMin * 70))
}

    }
```

The errors i'm getting:

> Returns total fare when called with a value that does not equate to a
> whole number of minutes
>
> ✕ AssertionError: expected 920 to equal 990
>
> Returns total fare when called with a value that does not equate to a
> whole number of minutes. Minutes must always be rounded up
>
> ✕ AssertionError: expected 500 to equal 570

Thank You

Comment: Look carefully at your `minutes` calculation. Why are you using `% 3600` (1 hour)? Why are you using [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) when the criteria says to round [_up_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)? Why are you using [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) on integers?

Comment: Thank you. Solved the first error now tryign to fix the last one:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To round up to the nearest whole integer, use [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)
2. Unless you want every hour to reset the price, I have no idea what `seconds % 3600` is meant to be for
3. [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) is useless on integers
4. You can calculate the *extras* multiplier by finding the `minutes - 3` or `0` if it's less than three minutes

```js
const FLAT_FARE = 500;
const EXTRAS_MULTIPLIER = 70;
const EXTRAS_THRESHOLD = 3;

function calculateTaxiFare(seconds) {
  const minutes = Math.ceil(seconds / 60); // round up

  return (
    FLAT_FARE + Math.max(minutes - EXTRAS_THRESHOLD, 0) * EXTRAS_MULTIPLIER
  );
}

console.log("545s =", `${calculateTaxiFare(545)}P`);
console.log("220s =", `${calculateTaxiFare(220)}P`);
```

Comment: Thank you; just amended to Math.ceil() and all is function correctly now: `4 Passing
0 Failing` Code amened at the top to reflect its functioning.

Comment: `@Mahmud`: If the response is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and upvote it.